# How to open a java project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

i just created a java project in eclipse and then closed it. Now i wanna reopen it, but when i click File > Open File then it shows me the folder of the project, but not a file to open the projects itself?
Can someone help?

A little edit: i just solved the problem. The package explorer was not shown up, don't ask me why.
I had to open i through:

> Window->Show View->Other...->Java->Package Explorer

This is really annoying if you ask me, but thanks for the help!

Comment: My Eclipse Neon has a File > Open Projects from File System menu item.

Comment: It should be in your left panel, should you not have deleted it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to open a existing project but it not listed, on Package Explore, you can copy the project for the current Workspace, and create a new project with the same name and Eclipse will load it.